# Why does the dialog in angular materials behave inconsistently?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using the dialog from angular materials (https://material.angular.io/). I have used this component actually alot and have followed the docs, and always gotten it work the way it does in the docs. But this time I am having inconsistent behavior. It works like normal for the rest of my app, but in one place in the app, the user has to scroll down a way, press a button, and then the dialog appears althought it appears against a gray background covering the entire rest of the app.

[image: It works correctly here]
[image: It the gray background covers my app]

Scrolling somehow seems to affect it, because when I move the button to a place in the same component so that the user does not have to scroll, it works as expected. What is causing this. How can I fix this so that the user can scroll to the bottom, but this gray screen will not cover the app?

Here is my code
This is the service that opens the dialog, it is the method called openDialog() that opens the dialog. I inject this serivce and call it throughout the app, and somtimes it works as expected and somtimes it puts up this gray backdrop.

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpResponseService {

  constructor(private local: LocalStorageService, private dialog: MatDialog) { }

  handleSuccess() {

  }

  handleHttpError(e: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if ( e.status === 401) {
      alert('** Your credentials are not valid. **');
      this.local.deleteLocalStorage();
      window.location.href =  environment.base;
    }

      let header = 'Error';
      let msg = '';
      if (e.error.errors) {
        header = e.error.message;
        for (const key in e.error.errors) {
          msg += key + ': ' + e.error.errors[key] + '\n';
        }
      } else {
        msg = e.error.message;
      }
      this.openDialog('** ' + header + ' ** \n \n \n' + msg);
  }

  openDialog(message) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogContentComponent, {
      width: '350px',
      data: {message: message}
    });
  }

  openConfirmation() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmComponent);
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log(`Dialog result: ${result}`);
    });
  }
}
```

As mentioned openDialog works most of the time. But when I have to scroll a lot on the page it throws this gray screen up in the background. If I move the button up the page so the user does not have to scroll then it works as expected.

Comment: *Scrolling somehow seems to affect it* how?

Comment: Could you please post your relevant code? Without it it's pretty much impossible to know what's going on, and therefore impossible to help you.

Comment: removing hasBackdrop will probably workaround your issue. other than that cant replicate your issue. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-klfejh?file=app/dialog-overview-example.html

Answer (score 0):

> it appears against a gray background covering the entire rest of the app

This sounds like the default behavior of MatDialog.

> How can I fix this so that ... this gray screen will not cover the app?

The `hasBackdrop` setting in MatDialogConfig allows you to control whether or not the dialog has the backdrop. For example:

```
this.dialog.open(MyDialog, {
    hasBackdrop: false
});
```

Comment: But why would the exact same dialog behave differently depending on what I believe to be if the user scrolls on the page? Also that didnt work for me. :(

Comment: You need to share all of your code so we can see what you are actually doing.

Answer (score -2):

I faced the same issue and after deleting this line in my styles.css:

html, body { height: 100%; }

is disappeared.